# How can random.choice be used to personalize a string?

Tags: python

```
import random
import time
from random import choice

My_List = ["Pizza", "Sandwich", "Apple", "Banana", "Rice", "Chicken", "Candy"]

print("Hello! I am Munchy and I am going to help you plan your dinner menu")
time.sleep (2)
answer = input ("For how many days would you like to plan for (1 - 7)? ")
if answer == "1":
print("Perfect! I think you will enjoy this!")
time.sleep (2)
print(random.choice(My_List))
elif answer == "2":
print("Perfect! I think you will enjoy this!")
time.sleep (2)
print(random.sample(My_List,k=2))       
time.sleep (2)
print("My personal favorite from those two would be ... ")
```

I obviously don't know what 2 items is going to choose randomly.
After it generates 2 random items I want my code to choose only 1 item from the 2 random ones it just printed

for example

if it picks rice and candy from the list i want python to say after that "My personal favorite from those two would be candy. OR rice but only 1 of the two

i hope i made the question as clear as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just save the two dinners you get from `random.sample(My_List,k=2)` in a variable and then use `random.choice()` on that variable. The full code is below.

```
My_List = ["Pizza", "Sandwich", "Apple", "Banana", "Rice", "Chicken", "Candy"]

print("Hello! I am Munchy and I am going to help you plan your dinner menu")
time.sleep (2)
answer = input ("For how many days would you like to plan for (1 - 7)? ")
if answer == "1":
    print("Perfect! I think you will enjoy this!")
    time.sleep (2)
    print(random.choice(My_List))
elif answer == "2":
    print("Perfect! I think you will enjoy this!")
    time.sleep (2)
    dinners = random.sample(My_List,k=2)
    print(dinners)
    time.sleep (2)
    print("My personal favorite from those two would be {} ".format(random.choice(dinners)))
```

I saved your initial two dinner selectionss to the variable `dinners` and then took a random choice from what was in `dinners`.

Comment: No problem. If this answer meets your needs, click the check mark to the left of this answer so that everyone knows the issue is resolved.